# Hiding my first GRE scores from university

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

I'm going to start applying to universities from 1st Dec onwards. In my 1st attempt of GRE, I scored 300. I'll planning to give my 2nd attempt on 21st November. I don't want to show my previous attempt score to universities and I'll receive my 2nd attempt scores around 5th December. Is it possible hide my 1st attempt score and pretend I haven't given GRE and fill my application form on 1st Dec. And on 5th Dec, when I get my score card (of 2nd attempt), I'll send it to the university pretending that was my 1st attempt. Is it possible to hide my 1st attempt score and send the GRE score after university deadline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's basically no reason to do this unless the first test marks you as having cheated on the exam or something exceptional in that direction.

Reasons to support what I'm saying: 
1. At most (all?) institutions, GRE scores compose only one small piece of a large part of your graduate admissions application.

2. Unlike the LSAT, the standard practice is to just use the highest score rather than average them.
3. For some institutions, the value of GRE scores is to filter out exceptionally bad applicants (though others don't do this at all). And this is generally done on the basis of just a single score.
4. For other institutions, it's more about getting you funding from the graduate school at larger than any particular interest of the department.

Since having had previously a lower score is not meaningful in most graduate applications, it's best just to include it. Conversely, engaging in shenanigans to hide your previous scores might draw unwelcome attention to you as someone who is trying to hide something.